# Solve for distance when given 2 speeds and a difference between the 2 in time

Tags: arithmetic

I was given a question in math class which asked this question:

Raj went Xkm in 90kmh to go to his work. One day he went 120kmh and shaved 16 minutes off of his regular time. What is X?

I was very confused and just wanted to see how this would be solved.

Comment: Do you know relationship between time, speed and distance?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: $d=rt$ allows you to set up equations. Give it a try.

Comment: Not much, I had this for my mathematics diagnostic in grade 10.

Comment: Here is a look at what I tried (t is time): 2X=(90(t))+(120(t+16))

Comment: Should be $X/90=X/120+16/60$. Now find $X$

Comment: Thank you. This solved my question. I guessed correctly lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward.

$V=D/T\rightarrow T=D/V$

So

$T_2-T_1 = D_2/V_2 - D_1/V_1$

Use $D_2=D_1$, simply solve for $D_1$ given the known time difference and the known velocities.

Answer (score 0):

I would naturally set up two equations for $X$ while considering the velocity in $\frac{km}{\color{blue}{min}}$, since the time difference is given as $16 \color{blue}{min}$:

- $90 \frac{km}{h} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{km}{min}$
- $120 \frac{km}{h} = 2\frac{km}{min}$

Now, the equations for $X$ are ($t$ is measured in minutes):
$$X = \frac{3}{2}t \mbox{ and } X = 2(t-16)$$

Solving for $X$ gives $\boxed{X = 96km}$